# Apply a visibility effect on a div using CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I'm having difficulties achieving my desired effect on my website project.

I want to hover my pointer and then a registration box appears. I don't have the menu drop down on login and products. But I can't do it on register. Please help.
**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <!-- enter code here -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="magazine">Magazines</a></li>
                <li><a href="audio.html">Audio CDs</a></li>
                <li><a href="dvd.html">DVDs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">login</a>
            <ul >
                <li><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" style="color:#939393" ></li>
                <li><input type="password" name`enter code here`="password" value="" placeholder="Password" style="color:#939393" ></li>
                <li><input type="button" value="login" style="color:#939393;width:158px" ></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
        <ul>
            <!--This is the div I want to show-->     
            <div id="register">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="">
            </div>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

and here is my CSS. note that Products tab and Login tab are working.

```
.menu { padding:38px 0 0 0; margin:0 ; width:380px;  float:left; font-size:13px}
.menu ul {list-style:none; margin:0;padding:0; }
.menu li {float:left;position:relative; }
.menu li ul{ position:absolute; top:30px; left:0; visibility:hidden; background:url(images/main_bg.gif);}
.menu li:hover ul{visibility:visible; z-index:20;}
.menu li ul li {float:none;}
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0 10px; border:0;}
.menu ul li a { float:left; margin:0; padding:12px 0; color:#939393; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;}
.menu ul li a:hover { color:#ddd;}
.menu ul li a.active { color:#ddd;}

.menu li:hover *#register{visibility:visible; z-index:20;}
#register {position:absolute; top:30px; left:0; visibility:hidden; background:url(images/main_bg.gif);}
```

the last 2 lines are the ones that doest seem to work. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct this section

```
<li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
<ul>
    <!--This is the div I want to show-->     
    <div id="register">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="">
    </div>
</ul>
```

with

```
<li><a href="#register">Register</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div id="register">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'login' link is a sibling of the popup, both contained inside the same `<li>`, whereas the 'register' link and the popup are in separate `<li>`s. If you set them up in the same way it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/GrERY/